# Cannot access Chinese webpages

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04, but had the same problem with my previous version (16 something).

99% of the time I am unable to access webpages hosted in China. Pretty much all of the pages I try to access - including major ones such as Baidu - will just not load on Ubuntu.

In Firefox, I get the following message:

> Hmm. We’re having trouble finding that site.

In Chromium:

> This site can’t be reached
>   baidu.com’s server IP address could not be found.
>   DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

But when I try on my Android phone or with my mac, there's no problem at all, the page loads in a second or two.

I have no clue as to where to look to find out what's wrong. Any suggestions?

(It's probably not relevant, but I'm located in Norway.)

Comment: Looks like a DNS issue on your Ubuntu box.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Any idea where I should start troubleshooting? Some terminal commands that could useful output for finding out what the problem is?

Comment: No idea. I only use Windows ...

Comment: You can **temporarily** edit your `/etc/resolv.conf` to point to a specific name server (OpenDNS: 208.67.222.222 & 208.67.222.220, or Google: 8.8.8.8).

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [Google's public DNS](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/).

If this does not work for you, then I remark that China is known to selectively block
incoming requests.

You might try to use a VPN service, if you have one available.

Otherwise, Google Translate is actually a proxy that is rarely blocked.
Just go to 
[translate.google.com](http://translate.google.com),
select Chinese as source and target, then enter
[pan.baidu.com/](http://pan.baidu.com/)
into the field and hit "Translate".
Google Translate might possibly break some of the functionality of the website.
If it works for you, then you know that you have been blocked,
and can search for better solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, and apologies for not responding earlier. It turns out it had nothing to do with Ubuntu... Kinda embarrassing that I dind't think about this earlier, but it seems to be connected to my VPN. I am connected to my VPN through wireguard, and as it turns out I am _also_ connected to it through OpenVPN. Killed the OpenVPN session and remained connected to my VPN through wireguard. Now I can access the sites with no problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

Manually set your DNS in your client.conf

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = 
Address = 192.168.99.3/24
DNS = 192.168.1.1

[Peer]
PublicKey = 
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = you.public.ip:port
```

The DNS ip is the dns of your server, you could get it by `cat /etc/resolv.conf`.

Also, you could set it to `114.114.114.114` or `8.8.8.8`.